# How to attach AJAX request to a certain post ID in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm completely newbie in AJAX, so I can't cope with such thing.

For example, I have some function:

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'some_fun');
 add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'some_fun');

 function some_fun() {
 $pt = get_the_title( $post_id = 1061);
 echo $pt;

 wp_die();

 }
```

and my AJAX side looks like this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('.bbb2').click(function () {
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: ajaxurl,
 data: {action : 'test'},
 success: function (data) {

  $('.result_area').html(data);
 }
 });
 });

 })
```

So, when I press the button with Class = .bbb2, my AJAX request returns the title of the post with ID = 1061 and shows it in the DIV with class = result_area.

But what if I want to retrieve the current ID/Title/etc. of my post? I don't want to specify it like this $post_id = 1061, I just want it to be $post_id instead. How can I force my AJAX request to see this ID?

I just want to be on a specific page, click on the button, and get a result such as Post ID, Post Title, Post Meta Data, etc.

Comment: What ajax url are you using? Are you trying the Rest API? www.yoursite.com//wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1061 this will retrieve everything about that specific post. I've done what you're looking for in the past using data attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing ajax is pretty much correct of what you have done here so far. However, its good to add a nonce validation i.e **[check_ajax_referer();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_ajax_referer/)**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'some_fun');
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'some_fun');

function some_fun() {
  $post_id = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );
  $pt = get_the_title( $post_id );

  wp_send_json($pt); //Use WP send json function

  wp_die();
}
```

On **jquery** side your implementation is almost correct but instead of passing static post_id value to the ajax function you can post the post_id from ajax itself.

For this you will need to pull out post_id from a post where your ".bbb2" button exists **( Again this is just an example there are alot of ways to pass this data into jquery )** For example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bbb2" data-postid="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">Click Here</a>
```

Now in the above anchor tag i have passed data as "postid". Now use that data to pull post id and pass post_id through ajax.

See below:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.bbb2').click(function() {
    var post_id = $(this).data('postid'); //Getting post ID from anchor tag

    //Compile the post data to retrieve
    var postData = {
      action: 'test',
      post_id: post_id,
    }

    //Make AJAX post call ( USE POST instead of GET to post data and get data in return)
    $.post( ajaxurl, postData ).done(function(result) {
    $('.result_area').html(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Now since you have access to post_id in your ajax function you can extract any information relation to that post.

Let me know if i misunderstood or if you have any queries regarding ajax calls in WP.

Comment: Hi, DpEN! Thank you so much. It seems that this is exactly what I need. I'll try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I pieced together an answer from similar code I had lying around. For your Button add a data attribute with the value of the current page ID:

```
<button class="bbb2"  data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    Get Post Data
</button>
```

Then get that ID with a click function and pass it to the rest function:

```
$('.bbb2').click(function () {
    var thisID = $(this).data('id');
    restPage(thisID);
});
```

And here's the magic rest function:

```
function restPage(id){

        jQuery.ajax({
            async: true,
            global: false,
            cache: false,
            url: 'http://www.yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            header: "Content-Type: application/json",
        }).done(function(data){

            //if data is returned or not
            if (!data) {
                alert("No Data Found");
            }else{
                var title = data.title.rendered;
                var pageContent = data.content.rendered;
                console.log(title);
                console.log(pageContent);
            }//END if (!data)
        });//END .done()
    }//END restPage()
```

Just logging the data to the console here but you can do what ever you like with it. Have a look at http://www.yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1061 to see all of the data you can get.

Comment: Hello, Paul. Thank you for this idea with WP Rest Api. I'll try it out.